# Transit visa for Indian national flying via Frankfurt to Sweden

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas

My son, an Indian national, has got admitted to a Swedish university.

After receiving his residence permit from Swedish immigration agency, he will be flying to Stockholm with a four-hour halt at Frankfurt.

Will he need a transit visa for Frankfurt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: No. Your son will enter the Schengen area in Frankfurt using his Swedish residence permit or visa.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate because the OP's son isn't simply transiting the Schengen area in Frankfurt; he's entering it.

Answer (score 3):

For border purposes, Sweden and Germany are located in the same "Country" (called Schengen), so he'll enter at Frankfurt with his passport and Swedish residence permit card and continue on a "domestic" flight to Sweden